# Given $2\cos(2α+β)+3\cos(β)=0$, find the value of $\tan(α+β)\tan(α)$

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $2\cos(2α+β)+3\cos(β)=0$, find the value of $\tan(α+β)\tan(α)$. The answer is $-5$. How to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $\cos(2\alpha+\beta)=\cos((\alpha)+(\alpha+\beta))=\cos\alpha\cos(\alpha+\beta)-\sin\alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta)(\cot\alpha\cot(\alpha+\beta)-1)$ might be useful.

Comment: 小学科学SSR, what did you try in order to solve your exercise ? Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and learn how to ask a good question on this site. Your post is being closed because it is a very low-quality question. Moreover, you should learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in order to write formulas in an appropriate manner.

Comment: What if $\alpha= \beta= 90^{\circ}$? Then your expression is undefined.

Comment: @GerryMyerson cotαcot(α+β) become 1/tanαtan(α+β) right? This is very useful! But still cannot get the exact value.

Comment: I have doubts that the problem is well defined. If $\alpha=0$, the value of the expression involving $\tan \alpha$ is zero and there is angle $\beta$ that satisfies the equation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson . This is what I have attempted. sinαsin(α+β)(cotαcot(α+β)−1)=-3cosβ
simplify it I get tanαtan(α+β) = 2sinα/-3cosβ + 1/2sinα. But I can't get the value of -5

Comment: **Hint** : eliminate $\alpha$ from the first equation and plug the result in the expression

Answer (score 1):

Set $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{4}$ then the equation becomes $-2\sin \beta+3\cos \beta=0 \implies \tan \beta=\frac{3}{2}$.

Thus, $$\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}+\beta)\tan{\frac{\pi}{4}}=\frac{1+\tan \beta}{1-\tan \beta}=\frac{1+1.5}{1-1.5}=-5$$

Comment: Why should $\alpha$ equal $\pi/4$?

Comment: @JohnBentin: The given identity should work for arbitrary values, no? Since we only need to find the value of  an expression, we can pick and choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that satisfy the given identity.

Comment: But that argument only holds water if you accept that the value doesn't depend on $\alpha$. It shows that *if* the value is constant, then the constant is $-5$, but why should we believe the value is constant? That's putting a lot of trust in someone we know nothing about.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It's a valid point. It's possible that the expression may have multiple values. However, the problem statement implies that it is a single value ("the value").

Comment: Yes, but faulty problem statements appear all the time on this website. We don't know anything about where the statement comes from, and we don't know that OP copied it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Wtite $\gamma:=\alpha+\beta$. Then
$$2\cos(\gamma+\alpha)+3\cos(\gamma-\alpha)=0.$$
Now use the expansions for $\cos(\gamma\pm\alpha)$ and collect terms to get
$$5\cos\gamma\cos\alpha+\sin\gamma\sin\alpha=0.$$
With the provision that neither $\gamma$ nor $\alpha$ is an odd multiple of $\frac12\pi$, the result follows after division by $\cos\gamma\cos\alpha$.